# ¿cómo solucionar el error events.js:183(error al ejecutar npm start) en React?

Tags: reactjs

al ejecutar  "npm start" me aparece el siguiente error, ¿alguién que pueda orientarme sobre cómo solucionarlo? Gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, procura colocar todo el stack del error, para saber en qué archivo y línea exactamente está ocurriendo el mismo. Así como está tu pregunta es imposible responderla o decirte algo más. Te invito a repasar [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

lo solucioné de ésta forma:
1.en C:\WINDOWS\system32 ejecute npm update fsevents --depth 8
2. Luego,Cd nombredetudirectorio
3. Finalmente, Npm start y funcionó